# Create a DataFrame using spark from an Excel file which is in server path

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a xls/xlsx file from server

With this code 
https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
SparkContext sparkContext = null;

sparkContext = new SparkContext("local", "234", sparkConf);
SparkSession sparkSession = 
SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(sparkContext).getOrCreate();

SQLContext sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext().newSession();
Dataset<Row> dframe = sqlContext.read().format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-mmm-dd HH:mm:ss").option("dataAddress", "'My Sheet'!A1").option("useHeader", "true").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false").option("inferSchema", "true")
            .load("/home/test/myfile/sample.xlsx"); // local path
```

This code perfectly works on local file

```
"/home/test/myfile/sample.xlsx"
```

How can i read files on server with path like this

```
"http://10.0.0.1:8080/serverFiles/test.xlsx"
```

I treid replacing the code with 
Server url above and got this error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: http
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2593)
```

Can spark read **xlsx/xls** file directly from server URL ?
[not for CSV]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use `HTTP` paths in your Spark Context.

Refer the this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684822/how-to-use-spark-scala-to-download-a-csv-file-from-the-web)

Comment: How can i do that in java .For xlsx file .I dont want to use CSV

Comment: here you go! refer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259339/how-to-read-a-text-file-directly-from-internet-using-java

Comment: This gives a scanner object  which again cannot be loaded using sqlContext

Comment: you can create a local file/String with this scanner and use parallelize to create RDD and create DF from it...

Comment: That is what i am doing and want to avoid it. Files has to be read using URL directly by spark . Not reading file object from url writting it in local file and reading it. I need to know weather there is a way in which i can read URL using sqlContext(This is what i asked in my question).

Comment: this not possible as far I know.. spark will accept all HDFS compliance data source.. but not from HTTP. That's why I suggested to get the file content to your driver and distribute it..

Comment: Welcome.... Keep us posted if you find a way to deal with it other than the suggested one. Will be helpful..!